# Hide server info using gke ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

We have a GKE instance where we are using an GCE class ingress, now we have a requirement to hide server info in response headers, there is any way to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to hide?

Comment: Hello @GariSingh, for example I what to hide this value "server: nginx/1.21.6" in the response header.

Comment: @nivarojas Please upvote/accept if my solution  has resolved your issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot directly configure response header manipulation using the BackendConfig resource or annotation on Service or Ingress, you can actually modify the underlying HTTP load balancer created by GCE Ingress:

```
gcloud compute backend-services update BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME
    --custom-response-header='server:'
```

You'll need to inspect the load balancer that was created in order to get the BACKEND_SERVICE_NAME, but at least you can do it.